# How to check programmatically whether the Scheduled Summary notifications is enabled by a user for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-push-notifications, ios15

In iOS 15, Apple has introduced **Scheduled Summary notifications**. We can schedule select app notifications to be delivered at a specific time of the day alongside others apps as a bundle. Is there a way to find whether the user has enabled this notification feature for an app programmatically?

Comment: Not sure why this has garnered close votes; this seems like a perfectly fine question for an iOS / Swift developer to ask.

Comment: @TylerH People who voted to close the question might not be iOS developers.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if scheduled summary notifications are enabled or not this way:

```
    let current = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    current.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { permission in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                switch permission.scheduledDeliverySetting {
                case .enabled:
                    // Show alert or do something
                    break
                    
                default:
                    // Do nothing
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    })
```